# How do I prevent new windows on one of my screens in Gnome?

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome, xorg, window-manager, sled

I am using tree monitors at work with SLED (Suse Linux Enterprise Desktop) 11. It works great, except minor thing. On my leftmost monitor I run VMware Workstation with Windows XP and I run it full screen. That means it covers everything including any toolbars on Gnome screen. This is exactly what I want: the dedicated Windows screen. The problem arises then I open new windows. Some windows would open up on the leftmost screens, ignoring cursor position, and will become completely invisible. To get to them I have to exist full screen mode in my Windows machine, find the window and drag it onto other screen.

Is there a way to prevent new windows from opening on one of the screens. The biggest cuprit is the Yast configuration applet. It always opens on the left screen.

I am using xinerama to layout three screens with two NVidia 9500 GT cards.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have been looking into this issue for some time with no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyboard shortcut `alt-space` to open the window options menu and then press M to select the move option. Then use the arrow keys to move the active window to whatever screen you want. (this works on windows and linux).

There is also [talk](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=618532) of a compiz plug-in that lets you determine where new windows show up.

You might also be able to use multiple desktops to your advantage. You can do a ctrl-alt-right arrow to use the next workspace or just click on whatever workspace you'd like to use in the bottom pannel (you might have to add workspace switcher if it is not there). Then when you open up yast, it will open up in that workspace instead of the workspace with windows.